# jquery datepicker onselect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery function:

```
$(function() {
    $("#iDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $('#frmDate').submit();
        }

    });

});
```

html:

```
        <form id="frmDate" method="post" action="<?php echo $base_url;?>index.php">
<input id="iDate" name="iDate" class='input' type="text" />
```

it doesn't seem to be firing, don't understand why it is not working.

cheers.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it with the console? What errors do you get?

Comment: use google chrome's console or firefox's firebug plugin to debug javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a comma in your javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#iDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $('#frmDate').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: sigh, just isn't my day today! Well spotted!

Comment: @bobo2000 a tip for the future...notice that the `onSelect` option in your question is not indented correctly which is caused from the missing comma (this bhaviour occurs in Visual Studio). Deleting and adding back the very last semi-colon will try to reformat the text again.

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery function is missing a comma

```
$(function() {
    $("#iDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable, <-- here :)
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $('#frmDate').submit();
        }

    });

});
```